# How to get the type of a variable

Tags: java, types, gettype

I'm pretty new to Java so please forgive my noob question.

How can I make the `error checking` logic syntactically correct and what built in methods might I use?

```
public static void initialize(HighScores[] scores) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    // capture input
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        System.out.println("Enter the name for score #" + i + ": ");
        String name = input.next(); // Alex
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Enter the score for score #" + i + ": ");
        int score = input.nextInt();
        // Error checking 
        // if the 'input' is NOT of type 'int'
        if (score.getClass().getSimpleName() != int) {
            // Ask to input a numeric value
            System.out.println("Please enter a numeric value! :)");
            score = input.nextInt(); // inputting a value in again
        }
        System.out.println();

        HighScores object = new HighScores(name, score);

        scores[i] = object;
    }
}
```

**What it would look like if correct:**

Enter the name for score #0:
Alex

Enter the score for score #0:
s

Please enter a numeric value! :)
5

Enter the name for score #0:
John

Enter the score for score #0:
3

.... etc...

Comment: If you don't enter an `int`, you will get an error here : `int score = input.nextInt();`

Comment: Your question is very deeply misguided.

Comment: `score.getClass().getSimpleName() != "Integer"`. I am not sure if getClass() will return primitives

Comment: I'd guess you're from a dynamically-typed background based on this question... Keep in mind that **Java is statically typed**. You don't need to get the type of the variable, because *it's already there when you declared it*. You wrote `int score`, so you know `score` *has* to be an `int`.

Comment: @Anoop That won't work because you can't call methods on a primitive type variable.

Comment: @Anoop - Reflection is not necessary. What would be the purpose of `Scanner# nextInt()` if he had to use reflection to check for the type?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to be confused,

```
try {
  int score = input.nextInt();
} catch (InputMismatchException ime) {
  ime.printStackTrace();
}
```

Will always be of type `int` (or you'll get an Exception), per the [`Scanner#nextInt()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt%28%29)

> Scans the next token of the input as an int.

and note that the throws says

> InputMismatchException - if the next token does not match the Integer regular expression, or is out of range

It is also possible to call [`Scanner#hasNextInt()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextInt%28%29) first,

```
if (input.hasNextInt()) {
  int score = input.nextInt();
} else {
  System.out.println(input.next() + " isn't an int");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First, as guys already mentioned in their comments you do not need this. If your variable is defined as `int` it *is* `int` and you do not have to check this.

Second, `int` is a primitive, so you cannot say `score.getClass()`.

However in some cases (if you write some generic code that must care about several, yet certain types) you probably want to fix your `if` statement as following:

```
Integer score = .....
.........
if (Integer.class.equals(score.getClass())) {
   // your code here
}
```